# How to remove suggested accounts from Thunderbird's dropdown list of From: accounts?

Tags: thunderbird, autocomplete

I am a Thunderbird email client user. I recently changed my ISP and therefore the email addresses. From wikipedia:

An email address such as John.Smith@example.com is made up of a local-part, an @ symbol, then a case-insensitive domain.

We have kept use of the same local-parts and changed only the domain when we changed ISP. Let's call them OldDomain and NewDomain.

I have not deleted the OldDomain email accounts because I don't know enough about Thunderbird to be absolutely confident that I will not lose the associated emails. (Some bad history here).

As a result, Thunderbird offers OldDomain and NewDomain addresses in From: whenever we start a new email. We have 5 addresses which means a total of 10 offered in the From: list. As a result we end up selecting OldDomain addresses in error and having "email not sent" hassles. How can I cut this list back to just the NewDomain addresses, please?

The addresses are:
HusbandsBusiness@OldDomain.com
WifesCommercial@OldDomain.com
Mailinglistsandsubscriptions@OldDomain.com
FamilyandFriends@OldDomain.com
Bookclub@OldDomain.com
HusbandsBusiness@NewDomain.com
WifesCommercial@NewDomain.com
Mailinglistsandsubscriptions@NewDomain.com
FamilyandFriends@NewDomain.com
Bookclub@NewDomain.com

Thunderbird does not allow me to remove the OldDomain email account addresses. I have removed from Thunderbird the passwords and the requirement to interrogate the OldDomain server from time to time. We no longer have any commercial relationship with OldDomain.

Very hard to google this issue for help due to the keywords involved. Sincere thanks in advance for insights into this one!

Comment: I understand you hesitate to delete the OldDomain accounts because you wish to conserve their emails. But why don't you create new folders and copy the old emails inside, to be sure of not losing them, then delete these OldDomain accounts?

Comment: Harry Mc - that's so obviously the right thing to do that I didn't think of it. Thank you.

Comment: I added an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if anyone is still watching this thread, but I had the same problem, and unfortunately the previous comments and reply above did not directly address the original poster's issue.  Maybe the user *can't*, or *doesn't want to*, delete the "Old domain" account?

In my case, I have 2 **active** email accounts managed by Thunderbird, so I can't just delete one.  The real problem is that the "From" drop-down menu (in a Write window) tends to get cluttered with a lot of alternate addresses which I had used in the past, but perhaps no longer use.  I just want to clean it up.  So there has to be a way to selectively delete entries in the "From" drop-down, rather than deleting an entire email account.

In fact, there is a way to do it.  Go to Account Settings (from the Tools menu, or from the Settings button at the lower left of the main screen).  On the Account Settings page, click on the account name of the account (in the left panel) which has the alternate from address(es) that you want to eliminate.  This brings up the main settings page for that account.  Click the "Manage Identities" button at the bottom of that screen.  A pop-up appears which should contain a list of addresses that are used in the "From" list.  There, you can select and delete the ones that you no longer want.
Hope that helps some folks out there.

Answer (score 0):

You hesitate to delete the OldDomain accounts because you wish to conserve their emails.

I suggest to create new folders and copy the old emails inside,
to be sure of not losing them, then delete these OldDomain accounts.